# Are there any ways to stop frenzy in other creature?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Let's say, a vampire or a lupine frenzies. What powers used **by someone else** may stop his frenzy? I am mainly asking about Disciplines, but any powers from oWoD would be very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a Thaumaturgy ritual on the old Vampire Players guide (and I believe in some old edition of Dark Ages) that can do specifically that.

> **Binding the Beast (Level Four Ritual)**
>
> This powerful ritual will pull a fellow kindred out of frenzy and even
>   separate the vampire from his Beast for a time. The ritual takes only
>   10 minutes to perform, and the caster does not have to see the
>   subject, but he must imbibe a full Blood Point of the frenzied
>   character's blood (it can have been drawn earlier) and push an iron
>   spike through his own hand (causing two Health Levels of damage that
>   can't be soaked). Upon completion of these acts, the subject suddenly
>   emerges from frenzy, and often becomes uncharacteristically passive.
>
> In truth, his bestial side has been separated from his psyche for a
>   number of nights equal to the number of successes the caster scores on
>   a Manipulation + Empathy roll (difficulty of 10 minus the subject's
>   Humanity). During this time, the subject cannot frenzy, cannot regain
>   Willpower, can only use one Blood Point per turn regardless of
>   generation, and cannot even feed without making a Courage roll. In
>   addition, the vampire must make a Willpower roll (difficulty 7) to use
>   any Discipline. Legend states that some Kindred have starved into
>   torpor after having been subjected to this ritual. The subject doesn't
>   need to be in a frenzy, nor does she need to be willing, but the
>   caster may never use this ritual on himself.

Exact place where you can find this ritual is on Vampire the Dark Ages Core Rulebook (Revised Edition) pages 170-171 (although the wording on that one isn´t exactly as my quoted text).

Comment: What is the source? I will accept the answer if you name the exact page of the exact book.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Edited to add exact book, exact page. If you find an old version of VtM: Players Guide (which I have left in another country...), you can also find it there in the level 4 rituals section of Thaumaturgy (can´t tell you exact page number of that one, since, you know...)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware, a Garou/Lupine doesn't as much frenzy as he activates his Rage ability. This functions very differently from the ravenous fugue state a Kindred is in when he/his beast Frenzies. Aside from staking the Kindred, putting him in Torpor or otherwise incapacitating him you can't directly end a Frenzy. That said, there are ways to give him a chance to snap out of it or to limit the damage he is about to do.

### Animalism

The most direct way is Animalism's level 3 power Quell the Beast. It's main purpose targets mortals and makes them into docile creatures that have no fight in them. Alternatively, it can be used to target a Kindred in Frenzy. Although it cannot truly cow the beast into a docile state as is the case with mortals, it can be used to soothe it. This gives the target a chance to reroll Self-control against the original difficulty, which might make him snap out of it. It has a drawback though, you need to touch the subject...

### Dominate

Though not even close to enabling you to pull a Kindred out of Frenzy, it might be used to redirect his actions. This is best used on a Kindred that is just beginning to Frenzy or on the verge as it will be much harder to do once combat has started. You could for instance get him to take a bite out of your arm instead of going to town on the crowd in an uncontrolled fashion. A Kindred that is just POed because someone slighted or embarrassed him is another story though. But a creative player should be able to come up with a way to handle it.

The difficulty to use Dominate on a Frenzying Kindred is increased by two and that to resist is lowered by two. Although you can argue that the beast will not so much try to resist as immediately attack anyone staring at him within arm's reach should you be unsuccessful.

---

I can't help but feel I'm forgetting something... Perhaps some obscure Path or Merit, I'll check my books when I get a chance!

Answer (score 1):

## Ask your Storyteller

It seems that no power can provide such a thing without Storyteller's approval. All that may help either directly tells you to ask your Storyteller or is written unprecisely. There could be other powers, but I presume that they would have such a problem too.

Some powers do not stop frenzy directly, but rather give the target a bit of time to overcome her Beast.

Sadly, there are so a lot of powers to induce frenzy, but so few to affect a frenzied vampire.

#### Animalism

Quell the Beast (Animalism ••• in V20) seems to be the most straight-forward way to do the job. However, as it requires 3 successes (~50% chance with a dicepool of 6, ~66% with 8) and still doesn't guarantee stopping of frenzy, it is very unreliable.

> Kindred cannot be affected by
>   this power.
>
> Though a vampire’s Beast cannot be cowed with this
>   ability, the Storyteller may allow characters to use the
>   “soothing” variation of this power to pull a vampire out
>   of frenzy. With three or more successes, the frenzying
>   vampire may roll again to pull herself out of frenzy, using
>   the same difficulty as the stimulus that caused the
>   frenzy originally.

••••• • Quell the Herd (Gangrel, Revises ed., page 61) allows to do the same thing to a group of frenzied vampires, but difficulty of the roll is 7 by default, making it even less reliable. Though, such an old/powerful vampire may have high respective dicepool.

#### Dominate

Dominate (mainly powers •, •• and ••••) may help, but it is also a hard way. By default, all difficulties to dominate a frenzying vampire are increased by 2, and it is damn a lot. One may prepare in advance with •••• Conditioning if, for example, attempting to control his own shovelheads, fully conditioned may be dominated without making an eye contact, and when it is just half-done, difficulty of Dominate is already lowered.

• may probably help with simple commands like "Stop!", or "Unfrenzy!", but not for long. •• is the thing you need. You would probably need to make a command such as "Listen!" before using ••, as it requires you both to be free from distraction. Against standard difficulty vs. frenzied vampire, 8, and dicepool of 8, your chances to succeed are 75% for each dominate attempt. If you lowered the difficulty by using ••••, against standard difficulty you will successfully dominate the frenzying vampire with a chance of 92%. If dicepool is 6, chances are 69% and 88% respectively.

Again -- it does not stop the frenzy, but it provides some control over a vampire, giving you some time.

#### Presence

This Discipline affects emotions. As with Dominate, difficulty to use it increases by 2 against a frenzied creature. As the Beast provides automatic successes for all Willpower rolls, spending a single Willpower point effectively blocks it. However, it may sometimes still work. Consult your Storyteller, there is no other way to ensure that it will work, Presence is written very unprecisely. Theoretically almost any power would do the job (though a bit differently).

#### Dementation

• Passion allows to prevent frenzy before it begins, or, probably, calm the Beast and help the target to stop frenzy.
Some other powers could probably also work, but I don't know this Discipline very well for now.

#### Chimerstry

May allow to project illusions in target's mind, for example, hiding the initial frenzy trigger from her sight. Difficulty is still +2.

#### Obfuscate

••••• Cloak the Gathering and/or ••••• • Conceal may hide the frenzy trigger from target's sight, helping her to overcome frenzy.

Answer (score 1):

**Abombwe level 3 - Whistling up the Beast**

The Laibon learns the "songs" that cajole and frighten the Beast Within, drawing it out of herself, or making others avoid confrontation.

*I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.  This level is less reactive so it seems to have little or no effect on someone who is already on frenzy.*

**Bardo level 7 - Bring Forth the Dawn**

The Child rolls his Occult + Manipulation ( difficulty, the Humanity of the Kindred targeted ). The number of successes is the number of hours which the Kindred will sleep. The Child can affect multiple targets by dividing his Dice Pool. Any Disciplines or Thaumaturgy rituals which protect the Kindred during the sleep will work in defending against this level of Bardo.

*It does not states clearly if could work on frenzied vampires but given the high level of discipline you can assume it does.*

Answer (score 1):

I believe most Disciplines have been listed already. However, since you asked about other powers as well, I'll chime in with one of my favourite Werewolf Gifts: **Calm the Savage Beast** from W:tA 20th Anniversary edition. This Rank 3 Homid/Children of Gaia Gift allows you to spend a Willpower and roll Manipulation + Primal Urge to immediately end the frenzy of another Werewolf. Spending another Willpower allows this power to be used on other types of supernaturals, such as Vampires, as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Serpentis 1*-Eyes of the Serpent** would be a strong contender for a low level ability.

> **V20 - pg209** No roll is required, but this power can be
>   avoided if the mortal takes care not to look into the
>   vampire’s eyes. Vampires and other supernatural creatures
>   can also be affected by this power if the Cainite’s
>   player succeeds on a Willpower roll (difficulty 9). If attacked
>   or otherwise harmed, supernatural creatures can
>   spend a point of Willpower to break the spell.

It doesn't stop frenzy but as long as you can keep the eye contact you can wait the rage/frenzy out.

Comment: Can you make your answer a bit more specific about what kind of ability is it, what edition is it from etc.?

Comment: Changed to reflect